How to make sure element has parsing precedence before other elements in pyparsing?
I have a simple markup grammar that can have matched and standalone tags:
{tag}Tagged content{/tag} plain text {standalone}{tag}Tagged again!{/tag}

I wrote the following pyparsing grammar:
import pyparsing as pp

pp.ParserElement.set_default_whitespace_chars("")
LBRACE, RBRACE, SLASH = map(pp.Suppress, "{}/")
IDENTIFIER_CHARS = pp.alphanums + "_"

TAG_NAME = pp.Word(IDENTIFIER_CHARS)

# Tags
OPEN_TAG = LBRACE + TAG_NAME("open_tag") + RBRACE
CLOSE_TAG = LBRACE + SLASH + TAG_NAME("close_tag") + RBRACE

# Forward declaring content due to its recursivity
content = pp.Forward()

# Main elements
TAGGED_CONTENT = pp.Group(OPEN_TAG + content + CLOSE_TAG)("tagged_content*")
PLAIN_TEXT = pp.Group(pp.CharsNotIn("{}"))("plain_text*")
STANDALONE_TAG = pp.Group(LBRACE + TAG_NAME + RBRACE)("standalone_tag*")

# Recursive definition of content
content <<= pp.ZeroOrMore(TAGGED_CONTENT | STANDALONE_TAG | PLAIN_TEXT)


test = "{tag}Tagged content{/tag} plain text {standalone}{tag}Tagged again!{/tag}"
p = content.parse_string(test, parse_all=True)
print(p.dump(indent=" "))

This currently matches first occurrence as standalone without pairing correct tags, which is another problem, but it highlights the situation I don't quite get. Why does it choose {standalone} as standalone and not {tag}. At this point it can match either way, but the TAGGED_CONTENT is first in MatchFirst list, so I expected it to have precedence.
It becomes worse when I try to extend grammar to support optional attributes that look like this (yeah, nasty markup, but oh well...):
{tag}Tagged text.|attribute|{/tag}

PIPE = pp.Suppress("|")
ATTRIBUTE = PIPE + TAG_NAME("attribute") + PIPE

# Updated
TAGGED_CONTENT = pp.Group(OPEN_TAG + content + pp.Opt(ATTRIBUTE) + CLOSE_TAG)("tagged_content*")


This doesn't work - the attribute is matched as PLAIN_TEXT along with actual preceding text. I would think Opt would match if possible. Is there maybe a stronger Opt alternative? Or maybe my approach is flawed in general?

I'm not sure I'm able to reproduce this. When I run your first posted code example, both of the paired tag tags are detected as tagged_content, and standalone is standalone. You are correct that MatchFirst gives precedence to the expressions in order, so TAGGED_CONTENT is checked first, and failing that, PLAIN_TEXT and then STANDALONE. Maybe revisit your example, and restate what it is that it does that is not what you expect.

Since this may involve an extended back-and-forth conversation (which SO discourages), perhaps you could post this as an issue on the pyparsing Github repo.

@PaulMcG I might've chose poor words. The pairing problem I talked about was that it would happily match stuff like <tag>Text</hello> and this is a different problem. What I am confused about is why doesn't it match {standalone} with {\tag} as standalone occurs first and TAGGED_CONTENT has higher precedence. So in my expectation the {tag} should be the STANDALONE_TAG.

There is a helper method match_previous_expr for doing this kind of thing, but after experimenting with your grammar, it is not handling nested occurrences well. Opened issue on pyparsing (https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing/issues/560)

@PaulMcG Thanks for opening the issue. Yeah, for some reason most of what I tried to do with nested parenthesis failed...

MatchFirst is how to define this precedence (as you have correctly done).
Add these lines after the content <<= ... line to see how pyparsing successively evaluates the expressions in content:
pp.autoname_elements()
OPEN_TAG.set_debug()
CLOSE_TAG.set_debug()
TAGGED_CONTENT.set_debug()
PLAIN_TEXT.set_debug()
STANDALONE_TAG.set_debug()

Here is first couple of dozen lines of debug output, showing the succession of expression tests until it successfully matches the first TAGGED_CONTENT (note that your grammar is recursive, so you'll see pyparsing try to match TAGGED_CONTENT inside the TAGGED_CONTENT expression as it works through the input):
Match TAGGED_CONTENT at loc 0(1,1)
  {tag}Tagged content{/tag} plain text {standalone}{tag}Tagged again!{/tag}
  ^
Match OPEN_TAG at loc 0(1,1)
  {tag}Tagged content{/tag} plain text {standalone}{tag}Tagged again!{/tag}
  ^
Matched OPEN_TAG -> ['tag']
Match TAGGED_CONTENT at loc 5(1,6)
  {tag}Tagged content{/tag} plain text {standalone}{tag}Tagged again!{/tag}
       ^
Match OPEN_TAG at loc 5(1,6)
  {tag}Tagged content{/tag} plain text {standalone}{tag}Tagged again!{/tag}
       ^
Match OPEN_TAG failed, ParseException raised: Expected LBRACE, found 'Tagged'  (at char 5), (line:1, col:6)
Match TAGGED_CONTENT failed, ParseException raised: Expected TAGGED_CONTENT, found 'Tagged'  (at char 5), (line:1, col:6)
Match STANDALONE_TAG at loc 5(1,6)
  {tag}Tagged content{/tag} plain text {standalone}{tag}Tagged again!{/tag}
       ^
Match STANDALONE_TAG failed, ParseException raised: Expected STANDALONE_TAG, found 'Tagged'  (at char 5), (line:1, col:6)
Match PLAIN_TEXT at loc 5(1,6)
  {tag}Tagged content{/tag} plain text {standalone}{tag}Tagged again!{/tag}
       ^
Matched PLAIN_TEXT -> [['Tagged content']]
Match TAGGED_CONTENT at loc 19(1,20)
  {tag}Tagged content{/tag} plain text {standalone}{tag}Tagged again!{/tag}
                     ^
Match OPEN_TAG at loc 19(1,20)
  {tag}Tagged content{/tag} plain text {standalone}{tag}Tagged again!{/tag}
                     ^
Match OPEN_TAG failed, ParseException raised: Expected TAG_NAME, found '/'  (at char 20), (line:1, col:21)
Match TAGGED_CONTENT failed, ParseException raised: Expected TAGGED_CONTENT, found '/'  (at char 20), (line:1, col:21)
Match STANDALONE_TAG at loc 19(1,20)
  {tag}Tagged content{/tag} plain text {standalone}{tag}Tagged again!{/tag}
                     ^
Match STANDALONE_TAG failed, ParseException raised: Expected STANDALONE_TAG, found '/'  (at char 20), (line:1, col:21)
Match PLAIN_TEXT at loc 19(1,20)
  {tag}Tagged content{/tag} plain text {standalone}{tag}Tagged again!{/tag}
                     ^
Match PLAIN_TEXT failed, ParseException raised: Expected PLAIN_TEXT, found '{'  (at char 19), (line:1, col:20)
Match CLOSE_TAG at loc 19(1,20)
  {tag}Tagged content{/tag} plain text {standalone}{tag}Tagged again!{/tag}
                     ^
Matched CLOSE_TAG -> ['tag']
Matched TAGGED_CONTENT -> [['tag', ['Tagged content'], 'tag']]

You can also add this line after the set_debug lines to generate a railroad diagram for your parser:
content.create_diagram(f"{__file__.removeprefix('.py')}.html")

